# Firefox waiting for response

Tags: python, firefox, webserver, timeout

I have set up simple python script that responds with hello:

```
def main(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [
        ('Content-type', 'text/plain')

        ])

    return 'hello'
```

Everything works fine in Chrome, I can refresh page every second
But in Firefox I receive 'pending' status and eventually after veeeeeery long time Firefox shows the respond message.

What's wrong here? I tried with Content-Length but it didn't help

Here are the responses:

No, tested with two different Firefox on separate machines.

Firefox:

> `Status=OK - 200`
>   `Server=nginx`
>   `Date=Thu, 24 Jan 2013 14:28:31 GMT`
>   `Content-Type=text/plain`
>   `Transfer-Encoding=chunked`
>   `Connection=keep-alive`
>   `Content-Encoding=gzip`

Chrome:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Server: nginx
>   Date: Thu, 24 Jan 2013 20:24:06 GMT
>   Content-Type: text/plain
>   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Content-Encoding: gzip

Comment: What does `start_response` do? Is this a WSGI setup?

Comment: Assuming you are using some WSGI web server stack, given that the spec says that your app should return an iterable, and the basic examples all show a list with a single string element, I'd start by seeing what happens if you `return ['hello']`.  While the string is an iterable, I'm betting that iterating over each character produces a more complicated operation or structure than you intend.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes it's WSGI

Comment: @sr2222 Yes It's WSGI web server stack. Even if I return ['hello'] why Chrome responds straight away (shows response), while Firefox (different machines, same result) has pending status ?

Comment: Can you show exactly what the server is responding with?  I'm thinking it could be an encoding or formatting related thing, but it's hard to get any idea at all when we don't know what you are responding with or what is happening under the hood.

Comment: Another thing; do you have any plugins installed/active in Firefox?

Comment: No plugins, I have also used two different machines to test this.

I have updated question with headers from both webbrowsers